# Use FirebaseUI in Webcomponent (Polymer 2.0)

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I successfully used Firebase-Auth SDK in Polymer and FirebaseUI in a plain js and now try to use it together (FirebaseUSI in a webcomponent). I get close but not quite there (e.g. styling).

[image]

Here is my webcomponent:

```
<dom-module id="damawi-signup">
    <template>
        <style include="fb-ui-style">
        </style>
        <paper-button raised on-tap="openUi">SignUp</paper-button>
        <paper-dialog id="dialog" with-backdrop>
            <div id="fbUIContainer"></div>
        </paper-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
        class damawiSignup extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'damawi-signup'; }
            openUi() {
                var uiConfig = {
                    signInSuccessUrl: '/signUpSuccess',
                    signInOptions: [
                        // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
                        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
                    ],
                    // Terms of service url.
                    tosUrl: '/TOS'
                };

                // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
                var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
                // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
                ui.start(this.$.fbUIContainer, uiConfig);
                this.$.dialog.open();
            }
        }
        window.customElements.define(damawiSignup.is, damawiSignup);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I linked the style information with

```
<link rel="import" href="../../src/fb-ui-style/fb-ui-style.html">
```

where I copied the firebaseui.css information

```
<dom-module id="fb-ui-style">
    <template>
        <style>
          @font-face{font-family:Roboto;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;...
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Any better solution already available or how can I improve the css?

Comment: Looks like the paper-dialog caused the issue. When you place

<div id="fbUIContainer"></div>

in the <template> (and not in the paper-dialog) it works nicely.